# Printer with good photo printing and ciss

Tags: linux, printer

I am looking for a printer which has a good photo quality. Moreover, a continuous ink supply system (3rd party is Ok) should be available. Also good support for GNU/Linux is desirable. Thanks.

Comment: Please try and give us more information such as budget, country of purchase and what kind of research you have already done.

Comment: Also, what paper types and sizes? Roll-fed or cut-sheet only? Dye or pigment ink? The more detail, the better.